# _IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath threw an exception 'System.Null Reference "

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I uploading files in asp.net core mvc i create folder for images in wwwroot with the name of photo and write a program in controller in which gives error of null _IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath can anybody help me.

namespace eHouse.Controllers
{

```
public class AddPropertyRentController1 : Controller
{

    Rentdb DB =new Rentdb();
    IWebHostEnvironment _IWebHostEnvironment;
    public IActionResult aprent()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult aprent([Bind] RentModel ar)
    {


        if (ar.imge1 != null)
        {
            string folder = "image/";
            folder += ar.imge1.FileName + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            ar.pic1 = folder;

            string serverFolder = Path.Combine(_IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folder);
            ar.imge1.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(serverFolder, FileMode.Create));
            
        }
```

Comment: You don't assign a value to `_IWebHostEnvironment` so it will, of course, be the default value for a reference type: `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have test your code, and I meet the same error as you. When I add  parameter to AddPropertyRentController1 to set the value for the `_IWebHostEnvironment` then the error disappear.

Try to add below code:

```
public class AddPropertyRentController1 : Controller
{
         private IWebHostEnvironment _IWebHostEnvironment;
         public AddPropertyRentController1(IWebHostEnvironment IWebHostEnvironment)
                {
                   _IWebHostEnvironment = IWebHostEnvironment;
                }
}
```

Comment: Simply adding code with no explanation does not make a good answer.

Comment: Ok, I update my answer , I will notice next time. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks its use full for me but now i have some issue in model.state in which validation state of pic is invalid and i put no validation kindly guide me    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                   

                    
                    string res = DB.Saverecord(ar);
                    string pics = DB.imagedb(ar);

                    

                    
                    TempData["msg"] = res;
                }

Comment: @CreativeThings  If my answer help you resolve your 'System.Null Reference ", could you please accept as answer? Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.  The some issue in model.state , you  can create a new post to describe the problem clearly so that we can help you.